# Redirect hazelcast logs to log4j2 logs

Tags: logging, log4j, hazelcast

I have hazelcast integrated in my application and it's working fine. My all application logs are correctly getting log in defined log file.

But all hazelcast specific logs are getting displayed on consol but not getting into log file.

do we need to do any specific configuration for hazelcast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to solve this need to set below properties

```
System.setProperty( "hazelcast.logging.type", "log4j2" );
```

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Setting_Up_Clusters/Logging_Configuration.html

Comment: The link in the answer does not seem to work anymore. This one is actual as for now https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-dev/manual/html-single/index.html#logging-configuration